# Why doesn't bootstrap dropdown menu work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seems to make a bubble dropdown appear with bootstrap.
I have the following cripts in my html head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/bootstrap-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
```

I have the following in my CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.dropdown-menu:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}
```

And in my HTML i tried to use the drop down with the following code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" id="submitButton" type="button" id="pops" >Select Populations</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap.css is twice? BTW, `http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css` points to CSS v3 and you are working with JS v2. First normalize that.

Comment: Okay I removed the import from my CSS. But I still can't get it to work.. It's odd I use the same code on my fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/49/

Comment: Also, if you noticed. it hides my the `...` in the code. That should appear in the bubble, so it does work, but when I click my button, I can't make it appear for some reason.

Comment: Do you have an online version of your code to test it?

Comment: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/

The select populations button is the button that should make it work. The code I've shown you here on stackoverflow is the code for this website.

Comment: @Vanquiza Doesn't look like you have `bootstrap.js` included on your page.

Comment: Okay thank you. I fixed it now so that it can be added. As it can be seen in my fiddle though, I have to click out of the bubbles frame for it to close again. On my website, it closes no matter what. I have check boxes inside of it, do you know how to prevent this? I've copy pasted my code from my fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kyle Needham is correct, you don't have bootstrap.js in the code on your page at
http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/